# In Powershell 5 what is the best way to parse forward slash and backslash from a string

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am accepting arguments to a script file for ServerName and Share. I want to make sure that the user does not add any leading or trailing forward slashes or backslashes.

Currently, I am doing this...

```
function validateServerShare($a_server, $a_share)
{

    $a_server = $a_server -replace'\\',''
    $a_server = $a_server -replace'/',''
    $a_share = $a_share -replace'\\',''
    $a_share = $a_share -replace'/',''

    $Path = "\\$a_server\$a_share"

    if(-not (Test-Path $Path)) 
    {
        haltError
    }
    return $Path
}
```

But I do not like the way I have to have multiple -replace lines. Is there a cleaner way or simpler way to strip forward and back slashes from a string, if they exist?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Have you looked at `Resolve-Path` ?

Comment: In the post you say "leading or trailing" slashes, but in the code you remove any slashes regardless of position - which one is it?

Comment: `.Trim('\/')` will remove forward and back slashes from both ends of the string, and not the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, enter a regex to hold the criteria to be replaced in a variable and then replace each occurrence of that criteria:

```
$a_server = "\\\sql2016\"
$a_share = "\temp\"

$criteria = "(/|\\*)" --criteria you want to replace


    $a_server = ($a_server -replace $criteria,'')
    $a_share = ($a_share -replace $criteria,'')


    $Path = "\\$a_server\$a_share"
    ## $path is now \\sql2016\temp
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution but I gave a +1 to @Mathias R Jessen for another good solution

Answer (score 2):

You can either chain your `-replace` calls:

```
$a_server = $a_server -replace '\\','' -replace '/',''
```

Or use a character class to match any of both:

```
$a_server = $a_server -replace '[\\/]',''
```